# what are the values of m when $m(3^{2m}+3) \equiv 0 \mod 28$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Can you help me with this problem.
I want to know what are the values of m which makes $m(3^{2m}+3) \equiv 0 \mod 28$.

Comment: my respect, but $m=0$ is intuitive i need the other values @Christoph

Comment: D'oh I'm Sorry it's all about my english.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, one solution is $$28|m$$

Else we need $$3^{2m}+3\equiv0\pmod{28}\iff 3^{2m-1}\equiv-1\pmod{28}\text{ as }(3,28)=1$$

Now as $28=4\cdot7,$  and $3\equiv-1\pmod4\implies3^{2m-1}\equiv-1\pmod4$

So the problem reduces to finding $m$ such that $3^{2m-1}\equiv-1\pmod7$

Now, $3^2\equiv2\pmod7,3^3\equiv-1$

So  $2m-1$ needs to be any odd multiple of $3$ i..e, $2m-1=3(2r+1)$ where $r$ is any integer

$\implies 2m=6r+4\iff m=3r+2$

Comment: Well, could you tell me why did you leave the m there, you just said $28|m$ and you left it away?

Comment: @Europeangoldfinch, Any $m$ that is divisible by $28,$ will satisfy the given condition

Comment: Awesome, another question if you could, How you did the first parity, you've multiplied $3^{2m}$ by $1/3$ to be $3^{2m-1}$, is that possible ?

Comment: @Europeangoldfinch, $$28|(3^{2m}+3)=3(3^{2m-1}+1)\iff28|(3^{2m-1}+1)$$ as $(3,28)=1$  Find $\#12$ of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Comment: That's clear, Thank you, I forgot divisibility properties.